Hyperlink with DBMail displaying full URL rather than hyperlinking inside XML table
I've got a DBmail script with an embedded XML table that works perfectly. However, I have one column which uses a dynamic field to create a URL. Within the XML table, I want this to be a hyperlink when sending the email. Currently, it displays the entire string in the email.
Here is my XML script - some identifiable bits cut out
SET @xml = CAST((
            SELECT 
                PolicyReference AS 'td','',
                BusinessUnit AS 'td','',
                PolicyDescription AS 'td','',
                CONVERT(NVARCHAR, ExpiryDate, 103) AS 'td','',
                ExpiryDays AS 'td','',
                ClientName AS 'td','',
                -- Create the hyperlink using HTML tags
               CONCAT('<a href="', PolicyLink, '">Go To Policy</a>') AS 'td','',
                FORMAT(CAST([Policy_Outstanding_GBP] AS DECIMAL(18,2)), '#,0.00') AS 'td'
            FROM 
                (SELECT DISTINCT PolicyReference, BusinessUnit, PolicyDescription, ExpiryDate, ExpiryDays, ClientName, [Policy_Outstanding_GBP], 
                    'https://app.powerbi.com/groups/&experience=power-bi&filter=PolicyAnalysisQuery%2FPolicyReference%20eq%20%27' 
                    + PolicyReference + '%27' AS PolicyLink
                 FROM TABLE_NAME a
                 WHERE ProductClass = @BusinessUnit) AS t
            ORDER BY ExpiryDate
            FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS
        ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX));

And here is the email body
-- Construct table for the current BusinessUnit
SET @UnitTable = '<p>' + @BusinessUnit + '</p>
        <table border="1" style="font-size: 10pt;">
        <tr><th style="background-color: #1E90FF; color: white;">Policy Ref</th><th style="background-color: #1E90FF; color: white;">Unit</th><th style="background-color: #1E90FF; color: white;">Description</th>
        <th style="background-color: #1E90FF; color: white;">Expiry Date</th><th style="background-color: #1E90FF; color: white;">Days</th><th style="background-color: #1E90FF; color: white;">Client(s)</th><th style="background-color: #1E90FF; color: white;">Policy Link</th><th style="background-color: #1E90FF; color: white;">Outstanding Premium</th></tr>' +
        @xml +
        '</table>';

In the email that gets sent, it displays the full URL in the column, the link works but it should be a hyperlink on Go To Policy
<a href="https://app.powerbi.com/groups/d3db31d9-199f-4b17-b34f-77db995e3f7c/reports/63088f&experience=power-bi&filter=PolicyAnalysisQuery%2FPolicyReference%20eq%20%27MYPOLICYREFERENCE%27">Go To Policy</a>

Can anyone help me at all get it to display as a hyperlink instead of the full URL?
Tried multiple variations of the code already but can't seem to get anything to work

Provide us with a complete [mre]. We have no sample data, nor your call to sp_send_dbmail

It should be : '<a href=""' + @xml +  '"">' +

Have you read Microsoft's FOR XML PATH documentation yet? Examples: Use PATH mode includes examples that allow you to specify values to attributes such as href.

You can add an attribute to FOR XML PATH using @ in the column name. Place it immediately before the same node's text data.

Do not use '' to delimit names, only use [].
Always specify a length for nvarchar.
You can simplify the subquery by using GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT, although why you need to distinct the data is not clear.
FOR XML generates nvarchar(max) if you don't specify , TYPE. You don't need to cast it.
ELEMENTS is the default anyway if you specify PATH.

SET @xml = (
    SELECT 
        a.PolicyReference AS td, '',
        a.BusinessUnit AS td, '',
        a.PolicyDescription AS td, '',
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), a.ExpiryDate, 103) AS td, '',
        a.ExpiryDays AS td, '',
        a.ClientName AS td, '',
        -- Create the hyperlink using HTML tags
        'https://app.powerbi.com/groups/&experience=power-bi&filter=PolicyAnalysisQuery%2FPolicyReference%20eq%20%27' 
           + a.PolicyReference + '%27' AS [td/a/@href],
        'Go To Policy' AS [td/a], '',
        FORMAT(CAST(a.Policy_Outstanding_GBP AS DECIMAL(18,2)), '#,0.00') AS td
    FROM TABLE_NAME a
    WHERE a.ProductClass = @BusinessUnit) AS t
    GROUP BY
        a.PolicyReference, a.BusinessUnit, a.PolicyDescription,
        a.ExpiryDate, a.ExpiryDays, a.ClientName, a.Policy_Outstanding_GBP
    ORDER BY
        a.ExpiryDate
    FOR XML PATH('tr')
);

